# How to move a file on remote FTP server to an directory on same FTP server using Net::FTP in ruby script

Tags: ruby, ftp

How to move a file on remote  FTP server to an directory on same FTP server using Net::FTP in ruby script. 
I know the file name and I have created a directory using ftp.mkdir but apparently there is no method to move file to the created folder.

Comment: See solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17351238/1533054

Answer (score 12):

Files (& Directories) can be moved using the `rename()` method of the `Net::FTP` Class. Example:

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new("ftp.myserver.com","myusername","mypassword")
ftp.binary = true
ftp.passive = true

path1 = "/original/dir/path/"    # Dir to move
path2 = "/new/path/"             # New path of Dir

ftp.rename(path1, path2)
```

And that's it! This causes all files to move from one path to another on the same FTP Server.

Comment: Do you happen to know why the leading '/' are required?

Comment: They aren't. But I just like to use `absolute paths` to avoid confusion later on.

Answer (score 1):

Try rename command. If it doesn't work, you can try the following command: "SITE mv oldpath newpath" . This tells the server to execute the command on the server. The expected behavior won't work on all servers but only on some, so use SITE command only when you are sure that it will work with the particular server.

Comment: Ya, I tried it like this ftp.sendcmd("SITE mv #{f} inProcess/#{f}").
Doesn't work .... gives ERROR: 500 Unknown SITE command.

Comment: @user2164844 Then the server either doesn't support SITE at all, or doesn't support shell commands via SITE. Then rename is the only alternative (IF it works)

Answer (score 0):

There are `putbinaryfile` and `puttextfile` instance methods. Is that not enough ? Or if you just want to move in a scope of ftp server, there is `rename` method.

Comment: I want to move in a scope of ftp server only.
Use case is that there will be to folders named inProcess and processed to keep the track of files in process and to be processed.