# Move entire directory and its contents to another location on the same server using Net::FTP in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ftp

As stated in the title, I would like to move a directory on a FTP Server to some other path on the same server. I want to accomplish this using `Net::FTP` but other solutions are also welcome.

Since there's no proper method for moving files or directories in [Net::FTP Documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html), a solution involving copying the directory to another path and deleting the original would be preferable.

Please stay on topic and leave solutions related to the question.

Comment: Well, I'm currently trying to use the rename() method to change path. And that's about it.

Comment: "Please stay on topic and leave solutions related to the question."? Do your questions have a problem straying? That's a pretty weird and uncommon request.

Comment: Hahaha, actually yes. It happens a lot. So I usually write this before downvoting their stupid answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the solution and it's quite simple. Files (& Directories) can be moved using the `rename()` method of the `Net::FTP` Class. Example:

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new("ftp.myserver.com","myusername","mypassword")
ftp.binary = true
ftp.passive = true

path1 = "/original/dir/path/"    # Dir to move
path2 = "/new/path/"             # New path of Dir

ftp.rename(path1, path2)
```

And that's it! This causes all files to move from one path to another on the same FTP Server.